# Decreasing support threshold for arules in R

Tags: r, associations, rules, arules, mining

I am working on association rules that are considered outliers.  I noticed that arules does not show results for rules that have a support less than .10.  Is there any way that I could view rules that have a support of .1 (10%) or less?

I tried the following code to try to filter out rules with less than a .1 support.  I suspect rules with less than a .1 support do not show up because there would be too many?  In any case, here's the code I'm using to see rules with less than a .1 support.  By the way, this code works when I want to see greater than anything over .1 .

```r
rulesb = rulesa[quality(rulesa)$support<0.1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the examples in `?apriori`:

```
data("Adult")
## Mine association rules.
rules <- apriori(Adult, 
    parameter = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.9, target = "rules"))
summary(rules)
```

Set `supp` to the value you like.